# Is this pointer variable inside parallel region shared or private?

Tags: c, multithreading, pointers, openmp

I had a quiz in an HPC course and I was somewhat puzzled by the following question.

> In the following C code, is the variable `*y` inside `foo_bar` function shared or private? Explain why.

```
int x;
#pragma omp parallel
foo_bar(&x);
...

void foo_bar(int *y)
{ ... }
```

The desired answer to this question is "shared", because of the variable `x`, which is defined outside the parallel region, but I think that this question does not make sense because `*y` can be shared or private depending on the context. And the question is explicitly about `*y`, it asks nothing about `x`. Also, how does one know if there is no other variable (say, `z`) defined in place of the ellipsis inside the parallel region and that `foobar(&z)` is not invoked there?

Or am I missing something?

Comment: If we go deep, I don't think `*y` is shared since it is pass-by-reference by the copy of the pointer.

Comment: The question is ill stated because `*y` is not a variable. It is an expression that is an lvalue and that designates an object when `foo_bar` is called as shown, and it may be referred to as “an object” to mean the object that it refers to. However, a “variable” in C is a combination of an identifier and the object it designates, although this is an informal term (the C standard generally does not use it in this sense in normative text). Thus `x` is a variable and `y` is a variable, and `*y` designates the object named`x`, but `*y` is not a variable.

Answer (score 0):

It's shared because it is a global variable and declared outside of a stack. `int x` would fall under the "data+bss" section of memory illustrated in this [Rutgers page](https://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~pxk/416/notes/05-threads.html) which is shared across threads.

Since `y = &x`, the question is really just asking if `x` is shared across the threads, though I do see how this can be confusing.

Comment: How does one know if there is no other variable (say, `z`) defined in place of the ellipsis inside the parallel region and that `foobar(&z)` is not invoked there?

Comment: It wouldn't matter if `z` was defined in the region and then `foobar(&z)` was invoked, since `z` would be placed on the stack, a function call from that thread would have access to that stack space, given that the memory was passed by reference. i.e. `&z`

Comment: And then wouldn't that `z` variable passed by reference to `foobar()` be thread-private?

Comment: @fortran your question about `z` looks like a different question. You should post it as such, with a code example that actually shows `z` being defined and used in the way that you are asking about.

Comment: @SolomonSlow There is an ellipsis (the multiple dots) in the code, which means that there is nothing that prevents one from admitting the possibility that `z` is definted within the code.

Comment: @fortran, You're missing my point, which is, If you have a question about a section of code, then that code should be visible in your question.  Don't try to use human language to describe what the ellipsis could represent: Show the code!

Comment: @fortran, You're also missing my other point, which is, If you have a follow-up question, don't ask it in a comment. Post a new question to the site.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Sorry if there is a misunderstanding. What I mean is that If I just add some code to the ellipsis, the nature of my question won't change because the code will just become a special case code, whereas now the code is more general. Since we have to think abstractly in programming, we must admit all possibilities for what can be contained in an ellipsis, up to the context in which the question is asked. This question asks about `*y`, nothing about `x`, `x` is just a special case variable. The ellipsis may very well contain a variable `z` defined within the parallel region.